# Are prices for EE 1.x to EE 2.x upgrade & CartThrob upgrade still $49.95 & $149?

Tags: cartthrob, ee1, ee2-upgrades

I'm helping a client quote an EE 1.x to 2.x upgrade and having trouble getting upgrading pricing from EE 1.x to 2.x. Before the site was changed my notes had the upgrade price as $49.95, is this still true?

Secondly, is the upgrade price for CartThrob for EE 1.x to 2.x still $149?

Nada on both sites, hope someone in here is in the know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close. The cost of an EE1 to EE2 upgrade is $50. (but what's 5 cents here and there ;)).

Sadly as far as I know there is no upgrade price anymore for Cartthrob from v1 to v2. CT2 has long been established and they've since brought out a slim lined version called Cartthrob Lite which just provides the basics. Unfortunately the cost of CT2 Pro has now gone up considerably to $300 and the support seems to now be absent in all areas so give it some careful consideration when quoting.